# CacheDuration in WebMethod ignored

Tags: c#, web-services, caching, webmethod

I try to cache a **webmethod** of a webservice. By following the documentation, I have tried to add the `CacheDuration` attribute, and made a test :

```
[WebMethod(CacheDuration = 180)]
public int TestCacheDuration()
{           
   return new Random().Next();
}
```

For each call of the webmethod, I have a different response, so it is not cached.

Is it normal ?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clearly explained in MSDN forums:

> There are two issues that can affect output caching in an ASP.NET 2.0
>   Web service application.
>
> In ASP.NET 2.0 the HTTP method of the test page has changed from GET
>   to POST. However, POSTs are not normally cached. If you change the
>   test page in an ASP.NET 2.0 Web service application to use GET,
>   caching works properly.
>
> In addition, HTTP indicates that a user agent (the browser or calling
>   application) should be able to override server caching by setting the
>   "Cache-Control" to "no-cache". ASP.NET applications, therefore, ignore
>   cached results when they find a "no-cache" header.

and also:

> Use protocols element under webSerices element in web.config:
>
> http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228319(VS.85).aspx

source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/3765f1e2-0ff5-4840-afa2-e85b3d909cd1

Comment: Ok, I use .net 3.5, but what is the aim of CacheDuration attribute, if the response is not cached ? If I understant, I may use <caching> attribue of web.config file ?

Comment: @malinois I think you need to read this answer again - it **is** cached as long as you do a `GET` instead of a `POST` and the HTTP header doesn't indicate "no-cache"

Comment: If I do only GET requests, the response will be cached, but it's not the case. With a GET request, the response is not the same, and Cache-Control:max-age=0 .

Comment: I have the same problem, its a Get request and the client does not send Cache-Control: no-cache and no matter what i try i get "max-age=0" its fustrating.... if i run the same code on a normal aspx page it works...